# How can I apply common theme settings to Microsoft controls?

Tags: winforms, themes

In WPF provides support to directly apply the theme settings like active color, fore color, background color, hover colors to system or microsoft controls(Button, check box, combo box and etc).

As like the WPF, it there is any possible way to apply theme style settings to windows forms controls(Button, CheckBox, Combobox and etc)?

Comment: Have you tried using System Colors for the color of your winform?  They should correspond to the Winodws Theme colors and change accordingly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.drawing.systemcolors.aspx

Comment: Of course you have to change the color of all of your components on your winform to System as well.

Comment: It already uses a common theme, your operating system's.  It is a Lego box, an example of somebody that snapped the pieces together [is here](https://github.com/peters/winforms-modernui).